# Visual Studio Developer Console cd into a different drive

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

So I have a total of three drives. 
C:\
P:\ 
and 
X:\

I use the developers console for Visual Studio to make C code (which I write with notepad, cause I'm stubborn.) and I don't know how to change directories from C:\ to P:\ from the Developers Console.

Any help would be advised.

Notes: I am not an admin, nor do I have access to an elevated command prompt.

Thank you
~Matt.

Comment: Also, I apologize if this seems rather noobish, but I prefer Linux over Windows any day. And in my class we use Windows 8.1 so I'm kind of flustered when it comes to these things. One other thing, I cannot download and install programs. I am just a little neophyte on this computer, thanks in advanced!

Comment: Just type `p:[Enter]` in the console to change to drive P

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel like a moron. Haha, thank you so much!

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Comment: From the console prompt, type help [enter] to get a list of the dos console commands. You can also get help for a particular command like help cd [enter] to get help with the cd command. You may want to learn how to use batch and/or make files to build your programs if you're not going to use the graphical interface to build programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the drive under a Microsoft OS, you type into the console

```
[drive-letter]:
```

and hit enter. In your case `drive-letter` is `P`, so

```
p:{hit the enter key}
```

now you are on that drive.

Note: Microsoft Operating systems these commands are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

type only d: and then hit enter, this works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).